# COMException (0x80040102) when trying to access autocomplete stream

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I'd like to access the autocomplete (nickname) stream in Outlook 2013, so that I could let user pick email address from a list.

I tried appropriating [this VB code I found](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e2f24841-0503-40fc-8d96-78a3523bb27f/how-to-access-outlook-autocomplete-stream-in-memory-not-the-cache-version?forum=outlookdev), however when I run this version, it throws an exception.

```
public byte[] GetAutocompleteBytes()
{
     Outlook.NameSpace n = ApplicationGlobal.GetNamespace("MAPI");
     Outlook.MAPIFolder f = n.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
     Outlook.StorageItem si = f.GetStorage("IPM.Configuration.Autocomplete", OlStorageIdentifierType.olIdentifyByMessageClass);
     Outlook.PropertyAccessor pa = si.PropertyAccessor;
     byte[] autocompletebytes = (byte[])pa.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x7C090102");
     return autocompletebytes;
}
```

The exception is "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040102) - Cannot create storage item in this folder. Either the folder is read only, or storage item is not allowed here" (but in my language, so forgive inaccuracies). I could not find anything that would seem relatable about this exception. It gets thrown right when f.GetStorage() gets called, and I am really confused, since I can see the storage item in OutlookSpy, and the creator of the code seemed sure it would work. I've read through [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/nickname-cache?redirectedfrom=MSDN) and few other sources, but found nothing that would help me resolve this. What am I missing?

Comment: The error is MAPI_E_NO_SUPPORT. Is that an IMAP4 or a GSuite store?

Comment: I'm not sure. What is the difference and how do I find out?

Comment: There are problems with associated items in in the IMAP4 store. Look in File | Account in Outlook.

Comment: Not sure what to look for, I can see nothing about IMAP4 nor GSuite there. Always ELI5, please.

Comment: So what kind of store is it?

Comment: I have no clue what you mean by that. Please explain more clearly.

Comment: When you look at that store in Outlook (File | Account), what kind of store is it? IMAP4? PST? Exchange? GSuite?

Comment: Could it be IMAP/SMTP?